# Generate HTML Pages from C Structures

Tags: c++

I would like to develop a application (i prefer c++), which will take C header file with lot of nested structures as input and generate a html page where the data will be presented as Hierarchial tree structures, which can be collapsed..

### file.h

```
struct level1
{
  struct level2
  {
     struct level3
     {

     }
  }
};
```

### file.html

[+] level1

I can collapse the level1 as below

```
[-] level1
    [-] level2
        [+] level3
```

Its for Learning purpose..and i am not sure where to start. Few pointers will be really helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hardest part will be parsing the C header files.  [GCCXML](http://www.gccxml.org/HTML/Index.html) will do that for you, outputting an XML structure that's then trivial to parse.

Comment: And then you can use XSLT.  :::Laughs evilly:::

Comment: +1 ..  Nice, didn't know that existed. Might be useful to incorporate into a bug reporting system for a C codebase.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to checkout **ctags** and **DOxygen** because they create HTML from various source code files for documentation purposes. Probably has what you need, and ctags I am sure will have C++ bindings.

Answer (score 1):

when you view an XML page in IE it uses an XSLT to turn it into this kind of collapsible tree structure. This XSL can be viewed by entering this in the address bar:

```
res://msxml.dll/DEFAULTSS.XSL
```

Personally I would use a similar method for your problem but if you must use C++ you can use the above to get an idea of what markup is required.

**EDIT** - I should have mentioned this before, that if you wanted to use the XSL method, you'll need to pre-process the header file into xml. This might sound long-winded but the two layers mean you can switch the xsl out to change the way it looks on screen whilst keeping the code that arranges what you want displayed separate. Over-engineering for a simple test project - maybe.

Comment: hi chris, i am getting page cant be found error when i enter res://msxml.dll/DEFAULTSS.XSL in address bar

Comment: interesting. what version of IE? I'm using 7. Are you on 8? There's a few other ways to get at this - here: http://forums.devx.com/archive/index.php/t-4702.html

Comment: Also, I need to add that you would need to do a little preprocessing on your header file to make it readable by the XSL. I should have pointed that out before.

Comment: That link I posted to view the source XSL will only work in IE. Converting XML into HTML with an XSLT will work in any browser (browser differences aside)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/)'s parser. It's supposed to have a pretty nice API.